# Avoiding to print uncited bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing LaTeX bibliography inside the main document with `thebibliography` environment. I have came across the problem where I have more `\bibitem` entries than I want to cite in my document. One solution would be to delete unneeded items, but can LaTeX hide uncited entries automatically?

To be more specific, how can I hide `bar` from appearing in the bibliography list?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\cite{foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{ab}
\bibitem{foo} foo

\bibitem{bar} bar

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Two suggestions, neither of which really answer your question, but you might find them useful.  The `refcheck` package will tell you if any entries are unused.  Also, if you use something like BibTex, it will only include things that you've cited.

Comment: @Mark thanks. It will be much easier to comment out.

Comment: use software like JabRef to manage your references and compose your bibliography with BibTeX.

Comment: I'd say `biblatex+Biber`…

Comment: You chose the manual approach to generate a bibliography, that also means you have to manually (maybe with the help of `refcheck`) ensure that only cited items are in the bibliography. Alternatives have been mentioned.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: @Johannes_B I ended up with sorting my 50 references by hand. Perhaps easier way of  managing references is to sort them alphabetically and then to cite them by the first author. I feel confident, that will suffice for me in the future.